# What condition can be used to check if a list of dataframes consist of dataframes or not?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list

I have two possible outcome values for a variable (returned from a function initialized as an empty list). It will either be a list of Pandas dataframes or [None]. How can I check this condition using if else?

I have tried,

```
if value[0]!=None and len(value)!=1:
    ....
```

I am getting the following error,

**ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().**

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
if all(isinstance(x, pd.DataFrame) for x in values):
    # do something
```

Example:

```
values = [None]

if all(isinstance(x, pd.DataFrame) for x in values):
    print('Test1: OK')
    
values = [pd.DataFrame([]), pd.DataFrame([])]

if all(isinstance(x, pd.DataFrame) for x in values):
    print('Test2: OK')
```

Output:

```
Test2: OK
```

Note that your error is due to `value[0] != None`, you can fix it with:

```
if value[0] is not None and len(value)!=1:
    print('OK')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Also how can I check whether two lists of dataframes are equal to each other or not? If I am using '==' to compare two lists of df's, I am getting the same error.

Comment: @royalewithcheese hard to answer without a reproducible example of the input to avoid ambiguity. `l1 == l2` does work to compare lists.

Comment: For instance, `import pandas as pd
values_1 = [pd.DataFrame([]), pd.DataFrame([])]
values_2 = [pd.DataFrame([]), pd.DataFrame([])]
print(values_1==values_2)`

Comment: `all(x.equals(y) for x, y in zip(values_1, values_2))`